# Simplify and Evaluate Trigonometric Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Here is the question:

> Simplify and evaluate without using a calculator:
>   $$\sin\pi/12 + \cos\pi/12$$

So, I think this is a trig identity question, but I am unsure of how to get started.  If someone could help me through this that'd be much appreciated

Comment: Note that $(\pi/12) = \frac{1}{2}(\pi/6)$. I looks like using a half-angle formula (of sum-of-angles) could be helpful. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @Mike Pierce I can recognize how from your example that could fit in here.  But I am more familiar with using the addition identities.  If you could help me via that method, I'd really appreciate it :)

Comment: Well, you can use $\frac{\pi}{12} = \frac{\pi}{6} + \frac{\pi}{6}$ or you can use $\frac{\pi}{12} = \frac{\pi}{3} - \frac{\pi}{4}$ like Demetri P points out in their answer. Just just apply either the sum-of-angles or the difference-of-angles (see [here](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/att14/formulalesson.htm)) formula for each of $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: @MikePierce  Be careful.  $\frac{\pi}{12} \neq \frac{\pi}{6} + \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{2\pi}{6} = \frac{\pi}{3}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, you're right, ... that's a bit embarrassing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  There exist additive identities for Sin and Cos.  Recall that $\dfrac{\pi}{12} = \dfrac{\pi}{3} - \dfrac{\pi}{4}$.  These values have exact representation.

Comment: could I use sin(A+B)=SinACosB+SinBCosA ?

Comment: Yup.  Since pi/3 and pi/4 have exact representation, you can find an exact value for $\sin(\frac{\pi}{12}$ using that identity.  Same for cosine.

Comment: so am I using two identities here? I think I still am a little confused

Comment: Sin has an additive identity.  Cosine has a different additive identity.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$\sin \frac{\pi}{12}+\cos\frac{\pi}{12} = \sqrt{2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sin\frac{\pi}{12}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos\frac{\pi}{12}\right) = \sqrt{2}\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{12}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right).$$

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$x=\sin{\frac{\pi}{12}}+\cos{\frac{\pi}{12}}.$$
Square it:
$$x^2=\sin^2{\frac{\pi}{12}} + 2\sin{\frac{\pi}{12}}\cos{\frac{\pi}{12}} + \cos^2{\frac{\pi}{12}}=1+\sin{\frac{\pi}{6}}=\frac32,$$
and $$x=\sqrt{\frac32}$$
($\sin$ and $\cos$ of $\pi/12$ are positive).

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of the $\pi/6$ angles...

You could also use the half-angle identities to calculate this result, using only the $\pi/6$ value.

Since $\pi/12$ is a positive angle in the first quadrant, you can use

$\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\theta}{2}}$ and $\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\theta}{2}}$ so that

$\sin\frac{\pi}{12}+\cos\frac{\pi}{12}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\pi/6}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\pi/6}{2}}.$

However your answer will be in terms of nested radicals...